# Check all Stack Exchange sites for new comments/answers

Tags: support, status-completed, notifications, email, stack-exchange

Can I check all Stack Exchange sites for new comments/answers to my questions without logging into each one?

Since my accounts are linked, I assume every SE site knows my usernames on every other SE site.

Answer (score 1):

You can be notified of them on any site, yes.  Look in the upper left above the logo.  If you have any notifications, there will be a red number to the left of this.  If you open it, there is an `Inbox` tab that will show your notifications for all of your associated accounts.

[image]

Comment: OK, that's what I thought too, but there've been times when I see nothing there (or see 1, read it, and then see nothing), but people have edited my post or updated comments. Does that not count?

Comment: @barry correct only *replies* are shown there (this does include edited replies, but it does not change the date of the original reply)